# c# - GetStringAsync never returns, proper way of doing async GET

Tags: c#, asynchronous, get, async-await, task

I have a console application where the user inputs a string (a number, "1" for example),  and I make a GET request according to the number entered, and return the string result of the GET.

I want to to do it in async, because in general, all I/O operations should be in async, so I basically want to do  the GET, wait for the result, and return the string.

**My Code:**

```
    public async Task<string> getClassName()
    {
        Task<string> myTask = getClassNameFromClassNamer();
        // Do something here
        string page = await myTask;
        return page;
    }

    public async Task<string> getClassNameFromClassNamer() /
    {
        string url = "...";
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            return await client.GetStringAsync(url);
        }
    }
```

Now, the **GetStringAsync** never returns, and the cmd window just closes.

I also tried with `ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);`, didn't  work.

When I tried to use

```
result = httpClient.GetStringAsync("...").Result;
```

it worked, but I get the feeling that it is not **really** async..

**I am Working in .NET 4.5**

**EDIT:**

**calling method:**

```
    public async Task execFeature()
    {
        string response = await webApi.getClassName();
        IResult result = new TextResult(response);
        result.display();
    }
```

**and:**

```
public async Task startService() 
{
    ....
    await feature.execFeature();
}
```

**and in Program.cs:**

```
featureService.startService();
```

So, I have 2 questions:

1. What is the proper way of doing an async GET to a server? I want to do the GET, get the string result and return the string.
2. From what I know, every web request should be done in async, because we want the other code in the app (UI, logic) to keep running. Even though **right now**, I don't have any other operations running or other UI to stay responsive (console application), and I am basically just waiting for the response from the server, I feel like its good practice to do the requests in async. Does that sound correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the code in `Main`? In main, you actually have to synchronously wait for the result. By the way, in your case, asynchronous IO calls are not needed.

Comment: thanks, edited my answer. so, should I just do it synchronously in my case? because it does make more sense, but on the other hand, you should do web requests asynchronously the keep the other stuff running, even though there isn't any other stuff now, just feels like good practice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the proper way of doing an async GET to a server? I want to do the GET, get the string result and return the string.

You are doing it correctly.

To fix the problem with your application exiting, you have to synchronously wait for the top level task in the `main` method like this:

```
featureService.startService().Wait();
```

Take a look at [this reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

> I feel like its good practice to do the requests in async. Does that sound correct?

Not really. Doing IO calls asynchronously is good in two situations:

- In a UI application, you don't want to tie the UI thread to make the UI responsive.
- In server side applications (e.g. ASP.NET) where you expect a lot of requests, you don't want to tie thread-pool threads while IO is going on. This is true because fundamentally, IO operations are truly asynchronous and [do not require any thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html). However, the "normal" synchronous IO calls do tie threads unnecessarily. So when we use the asynchronous IO calls, we save thread-pool threads which are expensive if you have a lot of server requests.

Comment: Got it. thanks, I will do it just synchronously, it does make more sense.

Comment: hey, I have another thing now, where I need to get user input in command line - and one of the features is to execute 200 http requests and get 200 words in return, and show it to the user.  is it still the best option to do it synchronously? how should I go about it?

Comment: @OfekAgmon, I suggest you add this as another question with all the details.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you are not actually returning what you want. You want to get the result of the async call. You would do something like this:

```cs
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var uri = "http://some.api.url";
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
   
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    
    return content;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, its also doesn't work , just like my code. on debug, after the line where you do the "getAsync", it never returns and the program terminates

Comment: Are you able to see what's going on with the other side of the call? On the API you're calling? Maybe it's just hanging on the API side. Does it ever actually time out?

Answer (score -2):

I've encountered the exactly same problem.

Adding ConfigureAwait(false) did the trick for me.

```
var response = await HttpClient.GetStringAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
```